# png image showing up with grey background in android

Tags: android, png, transparency, imagebutton

I have some png image buttons that I use in my app. But they are showing up with grey backgrounds on my page. Does android always show a grey background for a transparent one? Is there a work around?[image]

This is how it showed before.

[image]

This is how it shows after I made #FF000000 edits

[image]

This is how I want it to show.

 EDIT:
Error when I use #FF: 
 Color value not valid -- must be #rgb, #argb, #rrggbb, or #aarrggbb (at 'background' with value '#FF').  main.xml

Answer (score 20, accepted):

@android:color/transparent. Phoenixblade9 was close.

Comment: but imageview doesn't have a color attribute.

Answer (score 15):

If the image is transparent, there should be nothing shown behind the image.

The default colors vary from distribution to distribution.  The color scheme/theme for an HTC phone will be different than from a Motorola phone, or the emulator.

If you want to ensure that a view has a transparent background, set the following in your XML code for that view:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

This should ensure the background is completely transparent.

Comment: It shows up with a black background now instead of grey. Both in my emulator and in motorola droidx.

Comment: That would be correct then, that is the default background color for most versions of Android.  Perhaps if this isn't what you're looking for, you could post a screenshot and more description of your problem.

Comment: Sorry. I did not mention it before. I have a background above which I have these buttons. Previously it was a grey bg behind the img and now its black. Hope you get it. I can post pictures if you want.

Comment: Please do post pictures, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  Post them as an edit

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing this off the top of my head.   Give the new edit one more try.  It should work this time :)

Comment: Actually it is @android:color/transparent. Thank you for the help anyway. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Downvote for missing edit and therefore wrong answer.

Comment: @JamesCameron I think I omitted the edit because I didn't have the chance to test it myself, but I suppose if multiple people said it was that, I will trust it.  I edited my answer to the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

The code line  in the ImageView or ImageButton in the XML file is actually:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

I am writing this to help someone who is not familiar with the platform and won't connect the two answers above.

Answer (score 2):

I found this happens if you have `android:src="@drawable/mypngimage"` in your xml file. Instead if you use background then the gray area goes away and it behaves as expected. `android:background="@drawable/mypngimage"`

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your image is 32 bit depth or not. After that insert this code in your image view: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`.
To make your image transparent open Adobe Photoshop or Illustrator, open file (i.e. your image) and click file and click to export - save as web (legacy), tick transparent and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use #50FFFFFF (aarrggbb). in this format, aa is alpha channel to be transparency frequency. So If you use above color, you get a 50% transparent white background.